# Flutter build failed with exception

Tags: flutter, gradle

When I tried to run a flutter project it shows

> BUILD FAILED WITH EXCEPTION

```
user1@user MINGW64 /c/src/projects/app
$ flutter run

Launching lib\main.dart on Samsung Galaxy S3 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
>
> Build file 'C:\src\projects\app\android\build.gradle' line: 8
>
> What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
> Could not create service of type ComponentMetadataSupplierRuleExecutor using DependencyManagementBuildScopeServices.createComponentMetadataSupplierRuleExecutor().
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 55s
>   Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             77.7s
>   Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Can anyone tell why this happens, and how I can fix it, please?

Comment: try flutter clean

Comment: How to do that??

Comment: Did you solve it?